# how to check whether the element exists or not in pages

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My work is use selenium.webdriver class to click the button in pages with python.
If I am trying to find a element in page by xpath,sometimes the element may not exist.So before i use the element I should check whether the element exists or not.
The most popular way to solve this question is to use try...expect statement.
like this

```
    def ElementExists(xpath):
   try:
      driver.find_element("xpath",xpath)
      return True
   except:
      return False
```

It works well. But i find the time cost in try...expect statement is so long. It will cost almost **15 seconds**, so what can we do to reduce the time cost with another way?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A potentially faster alternative would get rid of the try and catch construction:

```py
def ElementExists(xpath):
    e = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath')
    if e:
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: In case of no element matching the `xpath` this will throw `NoSuchElementException` exception

Comment: It's a promising solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `driver.find_element` with `try-except` block you can simply use `driver.find_elements` method.
Something like this:

```py
def ElementExists(xpath):
    driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, your_xpath)
```

`driver.find_elements` will return you a **list** of web elements matching the passed locator. In case such elements found it will return non-empty list interpreted by Python as a Boolean `True` while if no matches found it will give you an empty list interpreted by Python as a Boolean `False`

Answer (score 0):

In my limited experience with the work, I find `driver.find_elements` is a good way to check the elements.Also we can use `css_selector` to improve the performance.

But if I want to reduce the time cost, the bottleneck of code performance is the parameter settings of the `implicit_waits`

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

`implicit_wait` tells WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find any element (or elements) not immediately available.

This means that every time you look for an element that doesn't exist, it waits 10 seconds. Reducing the time to 2-3 seconds will improve the runtime.

like this:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
```

Thanks to above answering for my question, it is inspiring for my exploration of the result.